# How to scroll and fetch the details of list item in a list using WDIO and APPIUM

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

I am currently working on a script to fetch the details in a list in an android APP using wdio and appium. Each item in the list is a card view; at a time, only one or two card views will be displayed on the screen (this might vary based on different screen sizes). How can I scroll and fetch all the elements in the list?